# Single Custom Adapter class for Multiple Spinners

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I have 4 spinners  in single layout page and each having different set of data from server. I had used Base-Adapter class (GETVIEW) method to set display member part.

My question is: Is possible to use single Base-Adapter class for multiple spinner controls? How to set different display member part in GETVEW method ?

Note: We are using WCF RESTful service to fetch online data.

Find below the sample code of in Base Adapter.

```
class EyeColorAdapter : BaseAdapter<MMS>
{
    List<MMS> items;
    Activity context;
    public EyeColorAdapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<MMS> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items.ToList();
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override MMS this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
        }
        // This is single spinner control display part. How to Check multiple spinner control condition here to set Display member part.
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position].WONO.ToString();
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Activitiy Class:

```
  public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        List<MMS> items1;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.72/eFACiLiTYPhone/mobileservice/WinPhoneWCFService.svc/listingworkorder/x");
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "GET";
                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                        }
                        List<MMS> myDeserializedObjList =
                            (List<MMS>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, typeof(List<MMS>));
                        Spinner spinr = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
                        spinr.Adapter = new EyeColorAdapter(this, myDeserializedObjList);
                    }
                }
                var request1 = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.72/eFACiLiTYPhone/mobileservice/WinPhoneWCFService.svc/listingworkorder/x");
                request1.ContentType = "application/json";
                request1.Method = "GET";
                using (HttpWebResponse response1 = request1.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var content1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content1))
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content1);
                        }
                        List<MMS> myDeserializedObjList1 =
                            (List<MMS>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content1, typeof(List<MMS>));

                        Spinner spinr1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner2);
                        spinr1.Adapter = new EyeColorAdapter(this, myDeserializedObjList1);

                        items1 = myDeserializedObjList1;
                        int index = items1.IndexOf(items1.Where(x => x.WONO + "" == Convert.ToString("INDIA2085")).FirstOrDefault());
                        spinr1.SetSelection(index);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.InnerException.ToString(), ToastLength.Long);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MMS
    {
        public string WONO { get; set; }
        public string EquipmentNo { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }
        public object Raised { get; set; }
        public string Hier { get; set; }
    }
```

I am new to andriod development. Kindly guide me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Can you post your Activity's code?

Comment: I have updated my activity class. Kindly refer

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and you can do it with a single adapter implementation.

Your requirement isn't specific, so I can think of two scenarios:

~  You have 4 spinners that display different data, but use identical layout.

> All you need are 4 different instances of a single adapter class. Each
>   instance will of course have a different array object as an an
>   argument in its constructor:

```
MyArrayAdapter adapter1 = new MyArrayAdapter(...., items1, .....);
....
....
MyArrayAdapter adapter4 = new MyArrayAdapter(...., items4, .....);

spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
....
....
spinner4.setAdapter(adapter4);
```

~ Second possibility is of having 4 spinner widgets, each with its unique layout.

> In this case, you will need to customise your getView() method. To
>   give you an idea, you will pass a flag in the constructor for your
>   adapter. Based on this flag, you will inflate a different view:

```
if (flag == 1) {
    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(R.layout.unique_layout_1, null);
} else if ( flag == 2) {
    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(R.layout.unique_layout_1, null);
}
....
....
```

Note that, in either case, you only need one adapter and multiple instances of it. Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: I have updated my Base adapter class and Activity . I am bit more confused for setting different instances for base adapter class.

Comment: @Kathir You are already using multiple instances of your adapter class `EyeColorAdapter`: here --> `spinr.Adapter = new EyeColorAdapter(this, myDeserializedObjList);` and here --> `spinr1.Adapter = new EyeColorAdapter(this, myDeserializedObjList1);`. What problem are you facing?

Comment: For multiple spinners with different data , i couldn't assign display member in GETVIEW method.

Comment: In GETVIEW method we are setting display member. But for multiple spinners how can we check , which spinner is called in GETVIEW and assign Display member against it? Kindly suggest.

Comment: @Kathir I am sorry but it seems that following a book or tutorial on Java and OOP concepts might be better for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable reply's and comments.